# Change Font and Size of a Tkinter Messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, tkmessagebox

i have a small Question and i finding no answer in the internet.
I want to change the font and fontsize of all Tkinter Messageboxes.
Maybe it would be possible if i change something in the libary but i dont now how.

Maybe somebody have an idea.

There is no option but maybe it would be posibble to change the libary to edit the size ...

Comment: You can't change font size in messagebox. There is no way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom style and from their change the font option, this is a sample code to change it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()

# Define custom style
style = tk.ttk.Style()
style.configure("CustomMessageBox.TLabel", font=("Arial", 14))

# Show messagebox with custom style
messagebox.showinfo(title="Title", message="Message", icon="info", parent=root, style="CustomMessageBox")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: line 7, in <module>
    style = tk.ttk.Style()
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ttk'

Comment: `messagebox.showinfo()` does not support `style` option.

Comment: Nope, that is not working